# How to achieve this low opacity gloomy light for background with HTML and CSS?

Tags: html, css

I've seen people make designs like this for their website. As you can see those two low opacity blue lights, one at the top right and the other at the bottom left. I am wondering how are they making this in HTML and CSS? I can make PNG out of this, but is there a way that can be done with HTML and CSS? I think it would load faster than a PNG file. Thank you in advance. :)

[image]

Comment: The glass effect is made with filter and inbox shadow, there is an example. https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-create-a-frosted-glass-effect-in-css--cms-32535. 

For the blue stamps I would recommend a ::after and ::before with box shadow, something like this:   box-shadow: 5px 10px 50px 10px blue;

Comment: Thanks if you can edit your post to include any code that you tried. I do feel like `filter` would be best but you could also do it with `gradient`. Have a read of this... https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: To get started, see: [CSS Tricks - Radial Gradient Recipes](https://css-tricks.com/radial-gradient-recipes/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried using this code.

### HTML:

```
  <body>
    <div></div>
  </body>
```

### CSS:

```
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #191b1f;
}

div::after,
div::before {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  background: hsl(199, 56%, 18%);
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  filter: blur(70px);
  mix-blend-mode: lighten;
}

div::before {
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  transform: translate(50%, -50%);
}
div::after {
  top: 50%;
  left: 0px;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
/*With gradient background*/
div {
  background: radial-gradient(
      circle closest-corner at center 125px,
      hsl(199, 56%, 18%),
      #191b1f 70%
    )
    no-repeat;
}
```

### Result:

[image: Result preview]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will look into the options you provided.

Answer (score 0):

For this method, the normally used styling is the backdrop filter method. By using that, you can create a frosted glass effect in CSS. First you should create a main div and then a sub div which we should create the backdrop effect. The method which I follows is:

1. Find a picture with similarity to the background.
2. Then reduce the brightness of the background image using `filter: brightness(48%);` and then I use the `backdrop-filter: blur(5);` to the sub div.

This is the exact same method which I was following for the past few months.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'll look more into the backdrop and filter CSS.